# Boto3 API for EMR doesn't support 'OnDemandPrice'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, boto3, amazon-emr

Having some trouble with creating an EMR spark cluster using `Boto3`. The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the RunJobFlow operation: Attempted to set bid price for on demand instance group.
```

I specified this configuration as follows:

```
 'Name': 'Core - 2',
 'InstanceRole': 'CORE',
 'InstanceType': 'i3.2xlarge',
 'InstanceCount': 50,
 'BidPrice': 'OnDemandPrice',
```

It seems the `Boto3` API doesn't allow this and I don't want to use the AWS Cli either. Is there a workaround to specify spot instances through `Boto3`?

Comment: Can you share the boto3 that you use currently which produces the error?

Comment: It is version 1.18.41

Comment: I mean, the code that produces the error.

Comment: It's way too long due to a bunch of configuration. 

But basically add this snippet

```
'InstanceGroups': [
            {
                'Name': 'Task',
                'InstanceRole': 'TASK',
                'InstanceType': 'i3.2xlarge',
                'InstanceCount': 1,
                 'BidPrice': 'OnDemandPrice'
            },
```

Comment: You can update the answer with properly format code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an open issue about this in the [boto3 repo](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2866). For the time being, if you specify `"Market": "SPOT"`, `BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice` will default to 100%, aka the on-demand price.

Here's an example using `boto3==1.18.42`.

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client("emr", region_name="us-east-1")

response = client.run_job_flow(
    Name="Boto3 test cluster",
    ReleaseLabel="emr-5.33.0",
    Instances={
        "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": True,
        "TerminationProtected": False,
        "InstanceGroups": [
            {
                "InstanceRole": "MASTER",
                "InstanceCount": 1,
                "InstanceType": "i3.2xlarge",
                "Name": "Master",
            },
            {
                "InstanceRole": "CORE",
                "InstanceCount": 2,
                "InstanceType": "i3.2xlarge",
                "Name": "Core",
                "Market": "SPOT",
            },
        ],
    },
    VisibleToAllUsers=True,
    JobFlowRole="EMR_EC2_DefaultRole",
    ServiceRole="EMR_DefaultRole",
)
```